# Upload of a file on Unix Server directory and it's retrieval using java

Tags: java, unix

I am trying to upload a file on Unix server directory and want to retrieve the same file using java.
Upload of file is successful, but when I am retrieving it then `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.
I am doing this by using a common init parameter declared in my web.xml file.
Code snippet and Web.xml is below-

```
<context-param>
  <description>Location to store test data verification uploaded file</description>
  <param-name>tv-file-upload</param-name>
  <param-value>//tmp//testdataverify//</param-value>
</context-param>**
```

I can see my file in my putty, folder is getting created and file also.

Java code I am using for Retreival of the file-

```
String filePath=getServletContext().getInitParameter("tv-file-upload");
        String filename="TestData_1.xls";
        String filenameD="TestData_1.xlsx";
        FileInputStream inputStream=null;
        try {
            inputStream=new FileInputStream(filePath+filename);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            try {
                inputStream=new FileInputStream(filePath+filenameD);
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fnf2) {
                fnf2.printStackTrace();
                request.getRequestDispatcher("ikeatvhome.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }
```

I am uploading a file from a window machine and this piece of code works fine If I have to upload a file in a certain directory in windows, but It is not fine while unix.

Note- File I am uploading is with the name of TestData_1.xls.

If any thing else is needed please let me know.

Is it an access issue or Am I using a wrong path or doing it wrong, Not Sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to log `filePath+filename` just to check that you're using the right path.